# How to let Google Calculator take degrees for sine/cosine calculation?

Tags: google-search, google-calculator

I was trying to calculate `cos29'` online but it gave me negative values. I guess it didn't realize that it was in degrees. I was wondering how to make Google Calculator work for degrees.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution by myself. There is a switch for controlling rad / degrees, on the top left corner of the calculator. Clicking on it will change the mode of an input unit.

[image]